# difference between Lambda expression and Action

Tags: lambda

i want know difference between Lambda expression and Action.?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming .NET

`Action` is a delegate type with no return value (and a generic `Action<T>` type is also provided which can take up to 16 parameters), where as a lambda is a nameless inline delegate instance.

Comment: +1 So a lambda that doesn't return anything can be substituted for an Action parameter.